# jQuery Autocomplete, serviceURL not getting the json file from php controller

Tags: php, jquery, json

im quite new to jQuery and php so this might be a easy fix, using devbridge [github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete](http://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete)
right now my code looks like this

```
    $('#supplier-search').autocomplete({
        
        serviceUrl: '...ajax/suppliers/',
        minChars: 1,
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            autoCompleteSupplier(suggestion.value); //this is calling another function if the suggestion is chosen
                                                                          
        }, 
        formatResult: function (suggestion, currentValue) {
            return suggestion.data;
        }
    });
```

it is working if i access the local json file with the autocomplete input of example 323
".../ajax/suppliers/323"

> {
>
> **"query": "323",**   "response": [
> {
> "value": "0323",
> "data": "Supplier323 - 0323"
> },
> {
> "value": "3230",
> "data": "Supplier3230 - 3230"
> },

but the autocomplete function is trying to access this json file
".../ajax/suppliers/?query=323"

> {
>
> **"query": "",**   "response": [
> {
> "value": "0001",
> "data": "Supplier1 - 0001"
> },
> {
> "value": "0002",
> "data": "Supplier2 - 0002"
> },

Looks like the query value is "" in the json that is being fetched and that gives me the whole list of suppliers, it probably has to do with the "?query=323" that is being added instead of just 323. The code i got in my php controller that is handling the json file is this:

```
 function suppliers ($query) {
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        $result = SupplierModel::selectAll ("
            AND (
                    name LIKE '%{$query}%'
                OR  number LIKE '%{$query}%'
            )
        ");
        $suggestion= array ();
        foreach ($result as $r) {
            $suggestion[] = array (
                'value' => $data[] = $r->get('number'),
                'data' => $r->getSupplierName()." - ".$r->get('number')
            );
        }
        die(json_encode(array (
            'query' => $query,
            'suggestion' => $suggestion
        )));
    }
```

And the HTML code:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Supplier number</label>
        <input type="text" name="supplier" id="supplier-search" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"/>
    </div>
```

I appreciate any feedback

Comment: Which autocomplete plugin is this supposed to be to begin with? I don’t suppose it is the standard https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/, because you are specifying options there that one doesn’t even have.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, that might be the problem because I got this "handed over" to me, according to the files im using this:
*  Ajax Autocomplete for jQuery, version 1.4.9
*  (c) 2017 Tomas Kirda
*  For details, see the web site: https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

change 'suggestion' to 'suggestions' in the following statement. 'query' not required.

```
    die(json_encode(array (
        // Query is not required as of version 1.2.5 //doc
        //'query' => $query,
        'suggestions' => $suggestion
    )));
```